# Let $G$ be an abelian group, K a group and $f : G\rightarrow K $ a group homomorphism. Prove that $f (G)\subseteq K$ is an abelian subgroup of $K$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, group-homomorphism

Let $G$ be an abelian group, K a group and $f : G\rightarrow K $ a group
homomorphism. Prove that $f (G)\subseteq K$ is an abelian subgroup of $K$.

I already proved that $f(G)$ is abelian, but I am not sure how to prove it is a subgroup of $K$. I need to show that it has the identity element, inverses, and closure. I am not sure how to show these 3 things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**:

1. (Identity) If $e$ is the identity element for $G$, then $f(e)$ is the identity element for $f(G)$.
2. (Inverse) $(f(a))^{-1} = f(a^{-1})$.
3. (Closure) $f(a)f(b) = f(ab)$.

It's easier to use the subgroup test, but you will need the ideas above anyway.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the inverse one? Why can you move the inverse inside the parenthesis?

Comment: @Housefire $f(a)(f(a^{-1})) = f(aa^{-1}) = f(e_G) = e_K$, so $f(a^{-1})$ is the inverse of $f(a)$ in $K$.